# c++ handling derived class that's self referencing

Tags: c++, design-patterns, derived-class, derived

So suppose I have a tree class like this in c++

```
class Node{
    void addChild(Node*);
    /*obvious stuff*/
    protected:
        Node* parent;
        vector<Node*> children
}

class specialNode : public Node{
    void addChild(specialNode*);
    /*obvious stuff*/
    /*special stuff*/
}
```

Now whenever I access the children in specialTree, I obviously get Node*, not specialNode*.

But this specialNode* has member variables and functions that Node doesn't have.

I can force specialNode to only have take specialNode as children and otherwise break in compile time,
but I still get Node* when accessing children/parent, and I have to cast it whenever I want to use special functions, even in specialNode functions.

Is there any clever, or just any better way to go about this? 
Other than literally casting every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need `SpecialNode` objects in your tree (and just want to encapsulate all generic tree functionality in `Node`) you can make `Node` a so called "mix-in" class like

```
template <class N>
class Node : public N {
public:
  void addChild(Node<N>*);
protected:
  Node<N>* parent;
  vector<Node<N>*> children;
};

class SpecialNodeBase {
  // Here comes all "special" data/methods for your "special" tree
};

typedef Node<SpecialNodeBase> SpecialNode;
```

After that you can construct a tree of `SpecialNode` objects and use all methods from `SpecialNodeBase` as well as additional tree-managing functions from `Node`

Comment: Wow...that's pretty sweet. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I might point out that by doing this, you've effectively defeated the purpose of inheritance - `SpecialNode` is no longer derived from `Node`, instead you end up creating independent classes with the same set of member variables.

Comment: I also was about to point out this 'inversion of inheritance' :). In fact, mix-ins can be used to model orthogonal (cross-cutting) features, for which inheritance would be suboptimal: Suppose you want to organize cars and persons in a tree. Neither cars nor persons 'are a' Node (which inheritance would mean). Using a `Node<Car>` resp. `Node<Person>` notion could be read as "Node of Car" and "Node of Person" which is imo more appropriate to this situation.

Comment: Note that the first version had an error: You have to use `Node<N>*` for `parent`, `children` and `addChild` (instead of `N*`)

Comment: In your example `Node` is a generic container for other objects - in that case, it's fine. I thought the OP's `specialNode` was a specialization of `Node` itself, since he also mentioned a `specialTree`.

Comment: Yeah, like Casablanca said, I did want a specialization of Node itself. I answered little too soon I think. I guess there's no perfect way around this. :(

Comment: If you have mixed objects (i.e. "ordinary" Nodes as well as "SpecialNode" nodes) in your tree, you'll have at least one special node which has a "normal" `Node` either as parent or as child. Therefore you'll have to do the cast anyway. As I tried to explain, my solution is for the case where you want the tree-related functions inside a `Node` class and want to define different trees with different type of nodes (but each tree having only one single type).

Answer (score 0):

Because addChild function in your child class is not polymorphism, make it virtual, but overloading functions across base/child members is not allowed, so we have to change the addChild parameter in the child class:

```
class Node{
    virtual void addChild(Node*);
    ...
}

class specialNode : public Node{
    virtual void addChild(Node*);
    ...
}
```

Now, it should work.

---

If you want to access to the `childeren` variable from the child class (`specialNode` class), you should cast it. For example:

```
specialNode* var = static_cast<specialNode*>(children[i]);
```

Since we declared addChild as a virtual function, then we should use `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast` if we aren't sure that `children[i]` is always an instance of `specialNode` class, and thus it is better to use `dynamic_cast`:

```
specialNode* var = dynamic_cast<specialNode*>(children[i]);
if(var != NULL)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but not exactly what the question was about.
Also, I'm pretty sure addChild(specialNode*) would just cover the scope of addChild(node*)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the "Mix-in" class solution won't allow you to call `addChild` from functions implemented by `SpecialNodeBaseClass`.

You can actually do the following:

```
template <class recursiveT>
class Base {
public:

     Base(dataType data) { populate children with data; }

     void addChild() { something base class appropriate; }

protected:
     std::vector<recursiveT> children;
};




class Derived: public Base<Derived> {
public:
     /* note: the constructor here will actually call the 
        constuctor of the base class */
     Derived(dataType data) : Base<Derived>(data) {} 
     /* other special functions go here.  */
};
```

This may look a little crazy, but it compiles cleanly for me on several GCC versions so I'm inclined to believe it's not totally wrong-headed.  You should now be able to call the functions of Base from inside Derived.

Answer (score -1):

You will definitely have to cast the `Node *` to a `specialNode *` at some point, but you can make this clean and easy to manage by doing this in only one place. You could add a member function, say `getParent` and override it in `specialNode`, like this:

```
class Node {
  ...
  virtual Node *getParent() {
    return parent;
  }
};

class specialNode : public Node {
  ...
  specialNode *getParent() {
    return dynamic_cast<specialNode *>(parent);
  }
};
```

Of course, this is assuming that `specialNode`s always have other `specialNode`s as parent/children. If you mix `Node`s and `specialNode`s, this obviously won't work.

Comment: You'll run into troubles if you define two otherwise identical functions with different return type (there are two `getParent` methods which only differ by the type of their return value)

Comment: @MartinStettner: Have a look at [Covariant Return Types in C++](http://www.lwithers.me.uk/articles/covariant.html) - this is allowed in the case of derived classes.